# struct2geno Error in scan file "line 1 did not have 167 elements : LEA R package for population genomics

Tags: r, genomics

I am trying to perform an admixture analysis with the package `LEA` and I am trying to convert a structure file into a geno file using the `struct2geno function.

My database consist in 512 samples/individuals and 82 SNPs marker (diploid).
The function is as follows:

```
struct2geno("mydata.txt", ploidy=2, FORMAT=1, extra.row=1, extra.column=2)
```

My structure dataset contains the first row in which I have sample ID, population ID and markers ID. The format is type 1, therefore markers are encoded using one row of data for each individual.

When I run the function I have the following error:

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
> line 1 did not have 167 elements

Since my first row is headers of input file I am expecting that it recognizes the sample ID, population ID and the markers ID. However, it seems it gives an error.

I tried to change the `extra.row` and `extra.column` to see if perhaps the layout imported was having some formatting problems, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Eleonora , welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks